# Box2D crash on collision

Tags: 2d, libgdx, collision-detection

I've got a really strange problem, that I can't solve whatever I try. So it's the following: 
I have 2 body's in Box2D, one, the player is a dynamic body, the other one, an obstacle is a static one. Now everything is fine, I can move my player around and everything, however as soon as he touches the obstacle, my game instantly crashes, no errors or something. I don't add or destroy body's while the game is ticking, so there shouldn't be a problem here ...... has anyone experienced something comparable and got a solution for it ?

Sadly I can't upload code right now as I'm on my phone, but I'll try to add some later

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? If yes, could you post an answer please?

Comment: Oh it’s been ages since then, but if I remember correctly it had something to do with invoking the physics stuff outside of the „regular“ libgdx application ....... reorganizing some bits and putting everything into a more controlled, central class did the trick for me ..... hope that helps